# Ошибка sql запроса, где проблема?

Tags: c#, sql

**Вопрос не актуален**

Где ошибка ? Как правильно сделать запрос ?

Цель, сделать запрос базе и если есть такой `id` , то получить от метода `true`, если записи нет, то `false`

```
    private bool PoiskIdVBaze(string s)
    {
        bool istina_id = false;

        SqlCommand Poisk_id = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [ParserDB] WHERE IdZadaniya = @Id_Zadaniya", sqlConnection);
        Poisk_id.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id_Zadaniya", s);
        int Kol_id = Poisk_id.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (Kol_id == 0)
        {
            istina_id = true;
        }

        return istina_id;

    } // Поиск id в базе
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Одинарные кавычки убери вокруг `@Id_Zadaniya`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov тогда будет другая ошибка, синтаксиса

Comment: Что-то не совсем понятно, в одном месте у вас `IdZadaniya`, в другом уже с нижним подчеркиванием `Id_Zadaniya` может в этом беда? Вы если написали без нижнего подчеркивания, то и пишите дальше это же имя.

Comment: @DenisBubnov верно можно и без нижнего, но только ничего от этого не поменяется...

Comment: @DenisBubnov не знаю что такое "хранимая процедура" - книжек не читал

Comment: На скриншоте конкретная ошибка: ожидается параметр, который не предоставлен. Решением является удаление ненужных кавычек. Точка. Различия между `ExecuteNonQuery` и другими методами запроса - другой вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (SqlCommand cmdSearch = new SqlCommand(
  "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [ParserDB] WHERE IdZadaniya = @Id_Zadaniya", sqlConnection))
{
  cmdSearch.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Zadaniya", s);
  return Covert.ToInt32(cmdSearch.ExecuteScalar()) > 0;
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: а ошибка то в моём какая ? вроде должно работать, что там не так ?

Comment: Нет, не должно, см. ссылки.

Comment: Прикрутил ваш вариант, аналогичная ошибка
https://image.prntscr.com/image/Yfd2AjF2QXaB7r0WoC3iSg.png

Comment: @Vipz каково значение переменной `s`?